# Как обработать клик на фрагменте?

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-on-click

Есть фрагмент с рисующим внутренним классом:

```
package ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch.fragments;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import ru.xpendence.development.gimstopwatch.util.MathHelper;

/**
 * Created by promoscow on 14.05.17.
 * Main activity for timer frame.
 */

public class Timer extends Fragment {

    private static int fragmentHeight = 0;
    private static int fragmentWidth = 0;

    DrawView drawView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("Timer.onCreate", String.valueOf(getActivity()));
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("Timer.onCreateView", String.valueOf(inflater));
        drawView = new DrawView(getActivity());
        return drawView;
    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        fragmentHeight = view.getHeight();
        fragmentWidth = view.getWidth();
        Log.d("fragmentHeight", String.valueOf(fragmentHeight));
        Log.d("fragmentWidth", String.valueOf(fragmentWidth));
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("onActivityCreated", "okay");
    }

    public class DrawView extends View {

        private static final long FPS = 200;
        private static final long TIME_DELAY = 1000 / FPS;

        private float[] coordinates = new float[5];

        {
            coordinates = MathHelper.defineDensity(getActivity());
        }

        private final float DENSITY = coordinates[0];
        private final float HEIGHT = coordinates[2] / coordinates[4] * 400;
        private final float WIDTH = coordinates[2];
        private final float DP_HEIGHT = 400;
        private final float DP_WIDTH = coordinates[4];

        {
            Log.d("Timer.density", String.valueOf(DENSITY));
            Log.d("Timer.height", String.valueOf(HEIGHT));
            Log.d("Timer.width", String.valueOf(WIDTH));
            Log.d("Timer.dpHeight", String.valueOf(DP_HEIGHT));
            Log.d("Timer.dpWidth", String.valueOf(DP_WIDTH));
        }

        private final Runnable mInvalidator = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public final void run() {
                invalidate();
            }
        };

        private final Paint mPaint = new Paint();
        private final RectF rectF = new RectF();
        private float angle;

        {
            mPaint.setStrokeWidth(20);
            mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

            rectF.set((WIDTH / 2) - (WIDTH / 3),
                    (HEIGHT / 2) - (WIDTH / 3),
                    (WIDTH / 2) + (WIDTH / 3),
                    (HEIGHT / 2) + (WIDTH / 3));

            angle = 0;
        }

        public DrawView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        }

        @Override
        protected final void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            mPaint.setColor(MathHelper.setBgI());
            canvas.drawCircle(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2, (WIDTH / 3), mPaint);

            angle = MathHelper.getAngle(angle);
            mPaint.setColor(MathHelper.setTimelineColor(angle));

            canvas.drawArc(rectF, 270, angle, false, mPaint);

            if (angle % 360 == 0) {
                angle = 0;
                MathHelper.setI();
            }
            postDelayed(mInvalidator, TIME_DELAY);
        }
    }
}
```

Подскажите, как обработать клик на этом фрагменте? Обработка onClick в материнской активити не даёт результатов.

Comment: А на что вы хотите слушатель повестить? Так то, с `Retrolambda`, например, это одна строка: `drawView.setOnClickListener(v->System.out.println("CLICK!"));`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб вроде как лямбды уже [доступны "из коробки"](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/java8-support.html#supported_features) на всех API (с Android Studio 2.4 P4)

Comment: Я хочу повесить слушатель на фрагмент. Фрагмент отрисовывает графику, вот хочу, чтоб обработало нажатие на эту графику.

Comment: @pavlofff, о, круто) Осталось подождать стабильной версии, а то на превью не хочется кодить после наблюдения неприятных багов даже в новых стабильных версиях пару раз)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы обработать нажатие на фрагмент, нужно в самом конце метода `onCreateView()` фрагмента (перед `return view`) прописать:

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //обработка нажатия
            }
        });
```